# Substring and similarity matching in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am learning to use elastisearch as alternative for database queries and I am not able to perform substring matches on the built index.
The mapping I have used to create index is

```
        "mappings" : {
           "user" : {
             "properties" : {
                "name" : {"type": "string"},
                "specialty" : {"type": "string" ,"analyzer":"snowball"},
                "address : {"type": "string" ,"analyzer":"snowball"}
              }
           }
          }
```

The document I am indexing is

```
    {
      "name" : "John Doe",
      "speciality": ["pediatrician","Child Doctor"],
      "address": ["#123 park road Abbeyville","#423 park road AbbeyTown" ]
     }
```

When I perform a search like

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/test/user/_search?q=speciality:pediatrician
```

I get the correct document

However when I search strings like

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/test/user/_search?q=speciality:pedia
curl -XGET localhost:9200/test/user/_search?q=speciality:pediatricians
```

No results are retrieved

P.S I know that wild cards can be used for matching but I need to be able to search for both the whole word and parts of the words based on user input so as to return the most relevant documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try reindexing after changing the mapping? Also try setting the search analyzer to snowball in the settings.

**UPDATE:**

You can go for wild card search. Better go for trailing wild card search alone instead of both leading and trailing wild card search.

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/test/user/_search?q=speciality:pedia*
curl -XGET localhost:9200/test/user/_search?q=speciality:pediatricians*
```

Comment: Yes I did reindex. Setting search analyzer worked partly but for queries like "pedia" still no results are being returned

Comment: Can you try `curl -XGET localhost:9200/test/user/_search?q=speciality:*pedia*` and `curl -XGET localhost:9200/test/user/_search?q=speciality:*pediatricians*`. This is bad practice considering the performance. But, just give it a try. If this works atleast we can come up with something in near future.

Comment: May I know the amount of data or type of queries you use in your search? I mean the total storage and do you use any advanced queries other than string query, something like scripts,facets etc?

Comment: As of now I am just starting with using elastisearch with rails so not using advanced queries yet, The amount of data is small(around 500 records).

Comment: @MayurRao please note that wildcards aren't scalable.

Comment: @NSmeef Considering OP's storage data, it should be scalable. I agree with your comment. That is the reason I mentioned it as bad practice. But, in certain scenarios you are forced to do that. Or worst case OP can remove the leading wild card.`curl -XGET localhost:9200/test/user/_search?q=speciality:pedia*` and `curl -XGET localhost:9200/test/user/_search?q=speciality:pediatricians*`

Comment: @VamsiKrishna that would help, I somehow missed the later part of your comment mentioning bad practise. Apologies. I only reiterated :)

Comment: @NSmeef My bad, I should have kept that in bold. No apology required for that. If that missed your view, it might miss many users too. So, I guess my recent edit should be visible to all :).